# Find the max and min of $f(x) = x^5 -x^4+x^2-x$

Tags: calculus

I get $5x^4-4x^3+2x-1$ for the derivative but I am not sure what to do after. The teacher told us that we would have to use Newton's method to solve the problem.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: You could use Newton's method, bisection, or many other numerical methods to find approximate solutions to where the derivative equals zero. However, there also are [algebraic methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) to solve quartic equations. Those methods are pretty horrendous, however.

Comment: Are you supposed to find the maximum and minimum on an interval or all $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs (Descartes' rule of signs) as a help.

Comment: This question has been asked few minutes ago!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To find the maximum or minimum of $f(x)$, you want to find where $f'(x)=0$. [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is used to find roots, such as the roots of $f'(x)$.

**Note:** This assumes you want to find the maximum and minimum on some finite interval. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, $f$ does not have an absolute maximum or minimum.